# Change ProfileImage in Drawer at runtime

Tags: flutter

I have a image in my Drawer sidemenu where the path to it is stored in a final object named `userdata`:

```
class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  MyDrawer({Key key, this.userdata}) : super(key: key);
  final User userdata;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          if (userdata != null) ...[
            DrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
                child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: userdata.image == '' || userdata.image == null
                            ? CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 50,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/avatar.png'))
                            : Image.network(
                                userdata.image,
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                      )),
```

When I am now on a page (`profile.dart`) where I can update my profile image (which is pushed by the drawer -`sidemenu`-)

How can I update the `userdata` object in the drawer class?

I found some ideas like streams, but is this really neccessary ?

edit: profile.dart

```
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyProfilePageState createState() => _MyProfilePageState();
}

class _MyProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _username = TextEditingController();
  final _email = TextEditingController();
  final _firstname = TextEditingController();
  final _lastname = TextEditingController();
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  String image = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    ProfileApi().getProfile().then((user) {
      setState(() {
        this._username.text = user.sId;
        this._email.text = user.email;
        this._firstname.text = user.firstname;
        this._lastname.text = user.lastname;
        this.image = user.image;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

.....

  changeUser() async {
    try {
      User userdata = await ProfileApi().updateProfile(
          this._username.text, this._email.text, this._firstname.text, this._lastname.text);

    //call some function here to update userdata in my drawer  <--

      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Profile updated');
    } on Exception catch (error) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: error.toString());
      return;
    }
  }
```

i also have a storage class where the userdata object is also provided:

```
class UserStorage {
  Future<User> getUserData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String userdata = prefs.getString('userdata') ?? '';
    if (userdata != "") {
      dynamic user = json.decode(userdata);
      return User.fromJson(user);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your `profile.dart` page content

Comment: i think i added the relevant parts from the profile.dart .. its just a simple form where users can update their user relevant data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your `userData` content in a global variable
`globals.dart` file

```
library globals;

ValueNotifier userDataNotifier = ValueNotifier(null);
```

Convert your `MyDrawer` class to `StatefulWidget` and remove the `User` variable inside it. Then use your variable in a `ValueListenableBuilder` widget

import 'globals.dart' as globals;
// ...

```
class MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  MyDrawer({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyDrawerState createState() => _MyDrawerState();
}

class _MyDrawerState extends State<MyDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      //...
            Align(
              //...
              child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: globals.userDataNotifier,
                builder: (context, userdata, _) {
                  return ClipOval(
                    child: userdata.image == '' || userdata.image == null
                        ? CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 50,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/avatar.png'))
                        : Image.network(
                      userdata.image,
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Finally in your `changeUser` function, simply change the content of your notifier

```
import 'globals.dart' as globals;
// ...


changeUser() async {
  try {
    User userdata = await ProfileApi().updateProfile(this._username.text, this._email.text, this._firstname.text, this._lastname.text);

    // simply change the content of userData
    globals.userDataNotifier = userdata;

    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Profile updated');
  } on Exception catch (error) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: error.toString());
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is great.. is it possible to assign the valuelistenablebuilder also to the internal storage? i have a class in my userstorage service, getUserdata() which also provides the needed userdata object? i added the userstorage service to my question :)

Comment: or is  it better to use 2 global entities (storage and globals) and in the service where i update the storage, i also have update the globals? but for me it feels a bit wrong to monitor 2 entites of globals